# casting to the date datatype

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a column named thedate that is varchar. An example of a row is:

Feb 29

I want to convert this value to a date because I want to compare it to today. I have tried to_date but I'm getting a strange value:

0001-01-29 BC

I want it to be 2012-02-29. Any idea why it is not working? I thought it would automatically put in the current year for me and for some reason the month is one behind. It is also listing BC which is not needed.

```
select to_date(thedate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from market;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data in the field is really "Feb 29", you're going to have to fill in the year yourself.  That's why it's giving you 1 BC.  Try this or replace '2012' with a function to get the current year.

select to_date('2012 '||thedate, 'YYYY MON DD') from market;

Comment: the pipe didn't work. I'm using postgresql. ERROR:  operator does not exist: "unknown" | character varying
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: to_date('2012 '|| thedate, 'YYYY MON DD')

Comment: @Glenn: +1 Thanks for the catch.  Was typing too fast.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select ('feb 29 ' || extract(year from CURRENT_DATE)) ::date
```